# from 1 channel array to 3 channel with if condition

Tags: python, numpy

**img** is a colored image(array of 3 channels ) .

**img_sc** an array of zeros of the same size as **img** but 1 channel .

this operation map the colors of the rgb image (a segmented image that contains 5 classes ) into an ID image containing the IDs of the classes :

```
img_sc[np.logical_and(np.logical_and(img[:,:,0]==170,img[:,:,1]==170),img[:,:,2]==170)] = 1
img_sc[np.logical_and(np.logical_and(img[:,:,0]==0,img[:,:,1]==255),img[:,:,2]==0)] = 2
```

in other words here  in the segmented image , the road is gray (170, 170,170) and its class ID is 1 , the grass is (0,255,0) and its ID is 2 , etc to other classes ,  so instead of having an image of colored pixels I’m having an array of 1 channel containing just the IDs .

I need to do the opposite of this operation , and converting the 1 channel array containing the IDs , that looks like this :

```
[[3 3 3 ... 4 4 4]
 [3 3 3 ... 4 4 4]
 [3 3 3 ... 4 4 4]
 ...
 [3 3 3 ... 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 ... 2 2 2]
 [3 3 3 ... 2 2 2]]
```

into a 3 channel array containing RGB colors :

```
[[[102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  ...
  [  0 120 255]
  [  0 120 255]
  [  0 120 255]]

 [[102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  ...
  [  0 120 255]
  [  0 120 255]
  [  0 120 255]]

 [[102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  ...
  [  0 120 255]
  [  0 120 255]
  [  0 120 255]]

 ...

 [[102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  ...
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]]

 [[102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  ...
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]]

 [[102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  [102 102  51]
  ...
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]
  [  0 255   0]]]
```

Comment: Your question is very hard to understand. Please try and break it down into separate sentences each with one idea and with full stops in between. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
h, w, c = img.shape
out = np.zeros((h,w,c))
out[class[:, :] == 1, :] = [170, 170, 170]
out[class[:, :] == 2, :] = [0, 255, 0]
```

May work, or

```py
h, w, c = img.shape
out = np.zeros((h,w,c))
out[class[:, :] == 1, 0] = 170
out[class[:, :] == 1, 1] = 170
out[class[:, :] == 1, 2] = 170
out[class[:, :] == 2, 1] = 255
```

Comment: both worked and was able to regenerate the desired images . opted for the first as it takes less space . thank u

Answer (score 0):

```
arr = np.stack((arr,)*3, axis=-1)
arr[np.where((arr == 1).all(axis=2))] = [170, 170, 170]
```

Comment: please contextualize a little more your answer